# How to install Oracle on OCI Compute Machine ?I

Tags: oracle

I have the following VM on OCI :

- Image : Oracle Linux 8
- Shape : Ampere Arm-based processor VM.Standard.A1.Flex, 1 core OCPU, 6 GB memory

I'm trying to install Oracle 21C XE.

I followed the steps on the documentation from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinl/installing-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-728E4F0A-DBD1-43B1-9837-C6A460432733).

```
sudo wget https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/otn_software/db-express/oracle-database-xe-21c-1.0-1.ol8.x86_64.rpm
dnf -y localinstall oracle-database-xe-21c-1.0-1.ol8.x86_64.rpm
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
[root@dev-machine-547547 temp]# dnf -y localinstall oracle-database-xe-21c-1.0-1.ol8.x86_64.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:14:03 ago on Sun 17 Jul 2022 05:30:15 PM GMT.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - package oracle-database-xe-21c-1.0-1.x86_64 does not have a compatible architecture
  - nothing provides oracle-database-preinstall-21c needed by oracle-database-xe-21c-1.0-1.x86_64
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Oracle 21c XE is only available for x86_64 processors. You appear to have a system with an ARM-based processor, and ARM and x86_64 are completely different processor architectures. You can't install Oracle 21c XE on this system.

Comment: Oracle tells you the exact issue: architecture mismatch. You need to check [the system requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinl/requirements.html#GUID-5213CB0F-0938-4187-886A-C2B9C03F491F) and find that only Linux x86_64 is supported.